# Product of 13 single digit-numbers greater than the largest possible product

Tags: c++

There is this Project Euler question: To find the largest of products of thirteen adjacent digits of a thousand-digit number.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
long long int largest=1, product=1, t[1000];
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    cin>>t[i];
for(int i=0; i<988; i++)
{
    for(int j=i; j<i+13; j++)
        product*=t[j];
    largest=largest>product?largest:product;
    product=1;
}
cout<<largest;
}
```

The above program yields 9020007328254001152 as the answer, which is almost a million times larger than the largest number that could possibly be the product of 13 single-digit numbers (2541865828329).

So, what is wrong with this program?

Comment: Use print statements to debug. You can easily debug this program if you haven't copied it from somewhere.

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to execute each statement singly and watch values of variables.  Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.

Comment: How do I use a debugger in Code::Blocks 16.01

Comment: Is your input really 1000 whitespace-separated digits?

Comment: @molbdnilo This got me too. But he could be copy-pasting those values

Comment: @Truth-seek ,look you are printing largest outside the bigger for loop(one that runs i). Your value 2541865828329=9^13, is possible only if first 13 indices in t array have 9 and the outer loop runs only once. But since your outer loop runs more than once, it is obvious that largest will have much greater value. Try shifting cout<<largest inside the bigger for-loop but outside the inner for-loop and your shall see your smaller "ranged(less than 9^13)" value. Or I guess you want to check that largest<product